# Recursive PrintTree() method for binary search trees not correctly printing

Tags: python, recursion, binary-search-tree

I'm writing standard code for creating a binary search tree in Python from a list L. The idea is to recursively print the tree in the format (data, left_subtree, right_subtree). It works with every list but when I take L=range(n) it just does not include the first element.

For instance when I do:

> **input:** `L=[3, 8, 1, 13, 5, 9]`
>
> **output:** `(3, (1, None, None), (8, (5, None, None), (13, (9, None, None), None))))`

but when i do:

> **input:** `L=range(4) #L=[0,1,2,3]`
>
> **output:** `(1,None,(2,None,(3,None,None)))`

Where did the 0 go?

It should be:

> **input:** `L=range(4) #L=[0,1,2,3]`
>
> **output:** `(0,None,(1,None,(2,None,(3,None,None))))`

This is my code:

```
    class Nodo:

      def __init__(self, num):
        self.left = None
        self.right = None
        self.num = num

      def insert(self, num):
        if self.num:
          if num < self.num:
            if self.left is None:
              self.left= Nodo(num)
            else:
              self.left.insert(num)
          elif num > self.num:
            if self.right is None:
              self.right = Nodo(num)
            else:
              self.right .insert(num)
        else:
          self.num = num

      def Print(self,nodo):
        if nodo:
          return "("+str(nodo.num)+","+self.Print(nodo.left)+","+self.Print(nodo.right )+")"
        else:
          return "None"

    def binary_tree(L):
      if len(L)>0:
        raiz = Nodo(L[0])
        for i in range(1,len(L)):
          raiz.insert(L[i])
        return raiz.Print(raiz)
      else:
        return "None"

    print(binary_tree(range(4)))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have `if self.num` but `self.num` is 0, so this evaluates to false. So second insert it sets the Node 0 to 1 at line `self.num=num`.

Comment: Oh! Thanks! I didn't realize that